# one public IP Address same service (https) for two website is working (different Domain name)

Tags: ip, https, service, url, public

One Public IP Address giving same service for two web site (Different DNS).
beirutmotorsparts.com - 66.96.147.120 - 443
alwaslautoparts.com - 66.96.147.120 - 443
One public IP can give 443 to one Web site (URL), How it is possible to two url same service (443)?

Comment: Have you tried doing your own research? Even ServerFault has **many** answers covering this topic. It is strange to see here somebody who had never heard of SNI.

Comment: Thanks. I was never heard SNI SSL. Today only I got the information about SNI SSL. Thanks once again.

Answer (score -1):

May be Apache configuration is not correct, NameVirtuahost not enabled in old apache server version.

#######################################
NameVirtualHost *:80
#######################################
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xyz.com
DocumentRoot /htdocs/xyz

#######################################
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName abc.com
DocumentRoot /htdocs/abc

#######################################

if you are using https connection then NameVirtual host can be configured in /conf.d/ssl.conf

Comment: How security appliance will allow from outside one public IP Address and one services (443) to two different Web site Page (Whether it is IIS, Apache or Nginx)